# Enumerating contacts and calendar events within an Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, add-in, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm researching requirements for a new Outlook add-in. I'd like to determine if the current version of the [JavaScript API](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/index.html) allows add-ins to enumerate all of the current user's contacts and calendar events. I need to sync these contacts and events against a third-party system using a REST API.

Is a "get contacts" and/or "get events" (bounded by a date) query possible using the native Outlook add-in JavaScript API?

I'd prefer to do this using the native JavaScript API, but this could be something more suited to an [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162981.aspx) call. Something involving [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#makeEwsRequestAsync), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mailbox API doesn't have any methods for accessing data beyond the context of the current item that the add-in is activated for.  So yes, [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj190901.aspx) is an option, as well as the [Outlook REST APIs](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/GetStarted).

EWS can be quite difficult to work with, as the XML requests and responses are time consuming to work with (one typo and you're screwed).  I would recommend the REST APIs instead.